# pwa orientation change off for polymer apps

Tags: polymer, progressive-web-apps

I create a web page(chrome & safari) for mobiles, I want to lock the screen orientation in portrait mode.

```
      "display": "standalone",
       "orientation": "portrait"
```

I added this one `/manifest.json` file but not working..I want to run my web apps only portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if your manifest is connected. You can check it from dev tools:

[image]

> The web app manifest provides information about an application (such
>   as name, author, icon, and description) in a JSON text file. The
>   purpose of the manifest is to **install web applications to the
>   homescreen** of a device, providing users with quicker access and a
>   richer experience.

Manifest should work on Android if your app is launched from homescreen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to fixed rotation even visiting using browser